# Matching two lists and create variables

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions

I have two lists of the same length. One of the lists has all the variable-names in it and the other one is a list of lists in which each list represents a value.
I now want to automatically create as many variables as the lists are long and assign each of the variable-names in the first list their respective value from the second list.
I tried it using Map but nothing seems to work so far.
How is this done in principle?

Comment: Please provide more detail, including the code you tried and the problems your encountered.

Comment: You want `MapThread`.  I am sure this was asked before. Try `ClearAll[a,b,c];
vars={a,b,c};
vals={1,2,3};
MapThread[(#1=#2)&,{vars,vals}]`

Comment: why not `vars = vals`?

Comment: @kglr yes that would work also. But I was answering OP about use of Map. He said he used Map and it did not work, I was just saying it should be `MapThreads` instead.